# Where can i download SETTINGS drive content?

Tags: boot, boot-issues, bootloader, settings

I accidentally deleted the content of /media/pi/SETTINGS

Anyone know if it's a problem ? Or could share me his Settings drive content?

I'm using Raspbian with NOOBS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tree of my `/media/pi/SETTINGS`. I think the only important file is `noobs.conf`.

```
pi@RPi9:~ $ tree /media/pi/SETTINGS
/media/pi/SETTINGS
├── cache
│   ├── data7
│   │   └── [0 ... f]    # [0-9,a-f] directories
│   │           └── *.d  # Bunch of files, not reproducible
│   └── prepared
├── installed_os.json    # I think only used for installation
├── lost+found
├── noobs.conf           # This file is important for boot selection
├── os                   # I think only used for installation
│   ├── Raspbian
│   │   ├── icon.png
│   │   ├── os.json
│   │   ├── partition_setup.sh
│   │   ├── partitions.json
│   │   └── slides_vga
│   │       └── [A ... G].png
│   └── Raspbian_Lite
│       ├── icon.png
│       ├── os.json
│       ├── partition_setup.sh
│       ├── partitions.json
│       └── slides_vga
│           └── [A ... G].png
└── wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Here is a copy of my `/media/pi/SETTINGS/noobs.conf` file.

```
pi@RPi9:/media/pi/SETTINGS $ cat noobs.conf
[General]
default_partition_to_boot=6   # 6 = mmcblk0p6 = Raspbian boot partition
display_mode=0                # 8 = mmcblk0p8 = Raspbian-Lite boot
keyboard_layout=us
language=us
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory `/media/pi`usually is used for mounting external storage devices, such as USB thumb drives,  USB harddisks, SMB/CIFS file sahres (if I'm not mistaken), and so on. When using the Pixel desktop, the next subdirectory will be the filesystem label of your storage device you've plugged into the Pi. Whatever you deleted inside `/media/pi`, it probably belonged to the contents stored on one of your external devices. It's gone now.